# Return or get/assign data from a SwingWorker thread to a variable. Beginner

Tags: java, swingworker

I'm playing with SwingWorker and learning from using it. So, I've this code:

```
ArrayList<Train> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Train> proccessedData = new ArrayList<>();

String query = "my query, not relevant here";

dataList = myApi.getTrainData(connectServer(), query, false);

TestNewThread tpp = new TestNewThread(dataList, threshold, pairs, false);

tpp.execute();
```

My TestNewThread class is:

```
public class TestNewThread extends SwingWorker<List, String>{

    private ArrayList<Train> dataList;
    private int threshold
    private int pair
    private boolean processFurther) 

    MyAPI myApi = MyAPI.getInstance();

    public TestNewThread(ArrayList<Train> dataList, int threshold, int pair, boolean processFurther) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.threshold = threshold
        this.pair = pair
        this.iprocessFurther)  = processFurther) 
    }

    @Override
    protected List doInBackground() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Train> list;

        publish("Starting process");
        list = processingTrains(threshold, pair, dataList);
        publish("Process finished.");

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        String mostRecentValue = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
        myApi.printPanel("\n"+mostRecentValue);
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
//        myApi .printPanel("\nALL DONE... !);
    }
```

Now what I need and I can't figure out how to do it is:
On the first piace of code here, where I've `tpp.execute();` I want it to return to an assigned variable. To something like this, note the commented section:

```
ArrayList resultsList = new ArrayList();
TestNewThread tpp = new TestNewThread(dataList, threshold, pairs, false);
resultsList = tpp.execute(); // I know I can't do this because .execute() is void but I want something like whatever the new thread returns to return to resultsList array.
```

If there is any typo or something on the code I'm sorry, I just made it now from the top of my head to explain my problem. I think you can get the idea from here.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of SwingWorker is to be able to do something asynchronously, without blocking the EDT thread. So you can't return anything from the `tpp.execute()`, because if you could, that would mean that the EDT would be blocked until the background task has finished, and the background task wouldn't be a background task anymore.

What you can do, though, is to pass a reference to the component using the SwingWorker, and invoke a method of this component from the done() method:

```
public class SomePanel extends JPanel {

    ...
    TestNewThread tpp = new TestNewThread(this, dataList, threshold, pairs, false);
    tpp.execute();

    ...

    public void backgroundTaskHasFinishedHereIsTheResult(List<Train> trains) {
        // TODO do whatever with the list of trains computed by the background task
    }
}
```

And in the SwingWorker subclass:

```
   private SomePanel somePanel;

   public TestNewThread(SomePanel somePanel, ArrayList<Train> dataList, int threshold, int pair, boolean processFurther) {
        this.somePanel = somePanel;
        ...
   }

   @Override
    protected void done() {
        List<Train> result = get();
        somePanel.backgroundTaskHasFinishedHereIsTheResult(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But, can't it be done by passing references to the lists?

Comment: Passing references to lists will allow you to add or remove items to these lists. But I guess you'd like something to happen in the GUI once the job is done. If that's the case, you need a reference to the GUI component that should be modified once the job is done.